# Need assistance with simple OpenGL ES 2.0 code

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am a complete idiot at OpenGL, and I can't figure out why my code isn't working, only the clear color shows. I am trying to set up some simple rendering on iOS. Please can somebody help me?

My main scene code is:

```
//
//  Scene.m

#import "Scene.h"

GLfloat vertices[] = {
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0
};

@implementation Scene
+(Class)layerClass {
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        CAEAGLLayer *glLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;
        glLayer.opaque = YES;
        glLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking, kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];

        context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
        if (!context) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to create 2.0 context");
            exit(1);
        }

        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];


        GLuint framebuffer, colorRenderbuffer;
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorRenderbuffer);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
        [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:glLayer];
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);

        GLuint vbo;
        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        GLuint program = [self loadShaders:@"Test.vp" frag:@"Test.fp"];
        positionIndex = glGetAttribLocation(program, "position");
        mvpIndex = glGetUniformLocation(program, "mvp");
        glLinkProgram(program); //added this
        GLint param;
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &param);
        if (param == GL_FALSE) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to link the program");
            exit(1);
        }
        glUseProgram(program);

        CADisplayLink *displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(render:)];
        [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)render:(CADisplayLink *)_displayLink {
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionIndex);
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionIndex, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid *)0);
    GLfloat mvp[] = {
        1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1
    };
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpIndex, 1, GL_FALSE, mvp);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionIndex);
}
-(GLuint)loadShaders:(NSString *)vertShader frag:(NSString *)fragShader {
    NSString *vertPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[vertShader stringByDeletingPathExtension] ofType:@"vp"];
    NSString *fragPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[fragShader stringByDeletingPathExtension] ofType:@"fp"];

    if (!vertPath || !fragPath) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to find paths of shaders");
        exit(1);
    }

    NSError *error;
    const GLchar* vertSource = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:vertPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error] UTF8String];
    const GLchar* fragSource = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fragPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error] UTF8String];

    if (!vertSource || !fragSource) {
        NSLog(@"Faild to load shader sources\n%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        exit(1);
    }

    GLuint vert, frag;
    vert = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    frag = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    GLint length = strlen(vertSource);
    glShaderSource(vert, 1, &vertSource, &length);
    length = strlen(fragSource);
    glShaderSource(frag, 1, &fragSource, &length);

    glCompileShader(vert);
    glCompileShader(frag);

    GLint success;
    glGetShaderiv(vert, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (success == GL_FALSE) {
        GLchar messages[256];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vert, sizeof(messages), 0, &messages[0]);
        NSLog(@"Failed to compile vertex shader\n%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:messages]);
        exit(1);
    }

    glGetShaderiv(frag, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (success == GL_FALSE) {
        GLchar messages[256];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(frag, sizeof(messages), 0, &messages[0]);
        NSLog(@"Failed to compile fragment shader\n%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:messages]);
        exit(1);
    }

    GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(prog, vert);
    glAttachShader(prog, frag);

    //Removed glLinkProgram()

    return prog;
}
@end
```

The shader code is:

```
attribute vec2 position;
uniform mat4 mvp;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(position.xy, -1.0, 1.0);
}
```

and

```
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try to use `glGetError` after calling gl functions. First you should give a try after `glUseProgram` and `glDrawArrays`. Waiting for results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionIndex);
glVertexAttribPointer(positionIndex, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
```

This line is incorrect:

```
glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionIndex);
```

Don't disable it before you use it, or you'll lose it

Also, since you are using a vbo for your verts, you don't need to do this:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(positionIndex, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
```

Simply switch it to this:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(positionIndex, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
```

You have a vbo bound to the GPU, it will use that buffer to draw. Use the `glVertexAttribPointer` to define the offset into the vbo it will find the first element for the given attribute.

@kibab The suggestion I made for the vbo is correct.

He was receiving `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` due to his attribute not binding to his shader. See comments below. As for the mvp you are incorrect, again.  The mvp is meant to convert points into a coordinate system of `-1.0, -1.0`, to `1.0, 1.0`. Meaning his vertices should be showing given their values.

See http://flylib.com/books/2/789/1/html/2/images/03fig02.jpg.

Also changing the z coordinate will do nothing for you. Change your vertice to start at -1.0,-1.0 and go to 1.0,1.0 a full screen box just so we can get something on screen.

Assuming you aren't using any apple provided gl classes your glViewPort isn't being set.

Try using your view's bound's size

```
glViewport(0, 0, bouds.width, bounds.height);
```

Also please put your verts on 0.0 z instead of -1.0

Also lets try this, just to figure out what's going wrong!
Try not using a vertex buffer object and passing it straight over like this.
Also don't worry about disabling your attribute at the moment, lets get something on screen first.

```
GLfloat     vertices[] = {  
            -1.0f,  -1.0f,  0.0f,
            1.0f,   -1.0f , 0.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f ,  0.0f,
            1.0f,   1.0f ,  0.0f,};

        glVertexAttribPointer(positionIndex,3,GL_FLOAT,0,0,vertices);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting some problems. If I change glVertexAttribPointer as you suggested, I still get the red screen, but if I only change the the glDisableVertexAttribArray, glDrawArrays revieves EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: It has suddenly decided that it should no longer crash on glDrawArrays, but I still just get a red screen.

Comment: Alright, the last piece of it that is wrong, is how you are getting the attributes. You must fetch the attributes prior to linking. So before glLinkProgram(prog); map your attribute

Comment: Thanks again (I love how there's always a kind person who is prepared to help me through my idiocy), I changed the position of glLinkProgram (new code here http://cl.ly/2i0D2T0g2X2q3Z3Y2a1l), but it still isn't working.

Comment: Small notice about: "Also, since you are using a vbo for your verts, you don't need to do this" - not only you "don't" but you must NOT use it that way, when VBO is bound, then this pointer is used as an start offset to bound VBO [link](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml) - this was a good reason for EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: You might not see painted triangles, because your `mvp[]` is set more like 'ortho' than 'perspecitve', and at position 0,0,0 (same where triangles would be painted) - so it's too close and it's clipped. You should see only red screen because of course glClearColor(1.0f{red}, ...). For a quick test try in your vertex shader `gl_Position = mvp * ...; gl_Position.z += 10.0;` (if still nothing then try `... -= 10.0;`)

Comment: Attempted changing the z coordinate in the shader, and completely removing the MVP matrix, but it still isn't working.

Comment: Ran out of space, so I moved my response into my answer. Cheers

Comment: Shaders are the same as the original, new Scene.m code is here http://cl.ly/3X0q053I2E3n1a1g2F2G

Comment: mvpIndex = glGetUniformLocation(program, "mvp"); has to be called after the link process. Make sure you do all the fixes I've stated. 
@kikab glValidateProgram isn't necessary to have a build, it only gives user feed back. Seeing how his shaders are simple, I know he's not running into any of the problems listed here http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glValidateProgram.xml

Comment: hmm, still showing up red. I commented out the VBO code, and changed the vertices and glVertexAttribPointer as suggested.

Comment: and your vertices are on the 0 z axis?

Comment: Yes, I am really confused over what I have managed to do here

Comment: If this is a personal project, I'd be more than happy to pull down the repo and fix it for you :D

Comment: Thanks for the offer. I have just had another go at getting some simple rendering in OpenGL ES by starting completely from scratch again, and the same thing is happening. This project is less cluttered, and I can base the other stuff on this if I can get it to work. The code is at http://cl.ly/1g1d0r0203001E1Z3n09, please could you have a quick look at it if you wouldn't mind?

Comment: here's everything that's wrong with what you just gave me. Please use             glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "position");
    glBindAttribLocation(program, 1, "color"); prior to glLinkProgram.  Don't forget to say     glUseProgram(program); at the end of shader loading. Finally     glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, positions);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors); The stride between your elements is 0. Use stride when you pack items into your vertex. For your example 0 is the correct answer.

Comment: I probably should have spotted all of those, thank you (updated version at http://cl.ly/3V2k1y400M201f2I2E2v). I am still getting a red screen though.

Comment: glViewport(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

Comment: Thank you so much @Nico! I will just use this code for the other stuff! Sorry that I am so stupid. :D